# How can I change Blender's output image resolution?

Tags: normals, resolution

I am currently trying to make a normal map for a texture I made. That texture has a 2048x2048 resolution. When I bake the normal map and save it to my desktop, the resolution of the normal map is only 1024x1024... I want the resolution of the normal map to be the same as the resolution of the texture file.
I have played around with the render settings, specifically changed the render res to 2048x2048 and increased the percent to 100 and 200, and every time I get the same 1024x1024 resolution!
Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For texture baking the resolution of the target image is what's important. The first step for baking is to create a new image in the image viewer where the normal map will be stored.

[image]

Here you can set your desired resolution.

[image]

If you use cycles, you need to add the texture node to the material of the object you want to bake to and select the image you just created. Next you can go to the bake settings in the render tab, mark selected to active.

Make sure you select the objects in the scene, the one that you want to bake to needs to be selected last (it has a bright orange outline). Then you can press the bake button and once it is finished, save the image from the image viewer.

Comment: Alright, first off, thank you for your message! Second, I already tried setting the resolution of the new image (where the normal map shows up after baking) to 2048x2048 but the normal map I saved only had the 1024x1024 resolution :/

Comment: Then you either selected the wrong texture to bake to (which was 1024x1024 instead of 2048x2048) or you have a previous save that was low res and wasn't overwritten with the new one.

Comment: Ok I got it to work! Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: @ivnplaysivnplays great! Please click on the checkmark next to my answer to mark this as solved.